# DB query for x day that no data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table contain multiple records for the name and `DT`, I need a query to check the Name don't have any new record in past 2 days based on the `DT`, how to create

```
Name     DT
ABC      2017-09-17 06:02:23.000
ACD      2017-09-15 06:02:23.000
```

Comment: Please, show table structure,sample data, and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You need something like this:

```
SELECT Name,dt
from
(SELECT Name,MAX(dt) dt
FROM your_table
GROUP BY NAME) a
where dt < GETDATE()-2
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your table schema or sample data this is a wild guess at a query, but what you want should be doable with the [GETDATE() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql). If you want to use UTC time you can also use the [GETUTCDATE() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getutcdate-transact-sql).

Edit: Updated to include the [ROW_NUMBER() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql).

Edit 2: Replaced the GETDATE() where clause with a CTE to exclude names that have dt within the last 2 days.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
    name
FROM table
WHERE dt > GETDATE()-2
)

SELECT
    name,
    dt
FROM (
    SELECT
        name,
        dt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY dt desc) AS rn
    FROM table
    LEFT JOIN CTE ON
        table.name = CTE.name
    WHERE CTE.name IS NULL
    ) tbl
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: this work, however, I have multiple record is that is same "name" and "dt"

how display the output select the only last entry unique name and dt

Comment: @andrew-obrien any luck?

Comment: Edited to include row_number.

Comment: My output for the query is 

abc      2017-09-18 02:48:33.000

But when I search * name=abc, I see the latest date for this row exists,

abc      2017-09-20 03:02:54.000

I need to show the name that is no new row in past 2 days

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that. The original where clause only looked at records older than 2 days but did not exclude names correctly. I updated this with a CTE instead.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I receive this error from the output

Msg 336, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'CTE'. If this is intended to be a common table expression, you need to explicitly terminate the previous statement with a semi-colon.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.

Comment: A CTE needs to be the first part of a statement. I'm not sure what your TSQL looks like, but your error suggests the CTE starts on line 33. Either end the previous statement with a semicolin, or place the CTE at the beginning of the query.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have corrected the query but now it's taking too long to run at least 3 minutes still waiting so I have stop the query, can we use another way to compare the latest "DT" with the system time if different more then 2 days then who in output

Comment: Do you have a chance to check

Comment: Sorry, no. You could crate a separate table of names that do not have a DT in the last 2 days and have an ETL job populate it every 5 minutes, however your data would then only be accurate to within 5 minutes. Instead, I would advise looking at your execution plan for missing indexes. This query will take up more memory the more names you have, but I don't see it taking 3 minutes with optimized indexes.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have tried run the query more than 20 minutes still no result.

Anywhere thanks for your answer

Comment: How many rows are you processing? This shouldn't be taking that long unless you have missing indexes which should be called out if you display your execution plan.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I think it's a problem to process million of records, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE #CM (Name  NVARCHAR(06), DT DATETIME)


INSERT INTO #CM
SELECT  'ABC','2017-09-17 06:02:23.000' UNION ALL
SELECT  'ACD','2017-09-15 06:02:23.000'


SELECT * FROM #CM
WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(105),dt) < CONVERT(NVARCHAR(105),GETDATE()-2)

ROLLBACK TRAN
```